# Issue sending Outlook invitations in a Windows service developed in C#

Tags: c#, windows, service, icalendar

We have developed a console application in C# to send invitations .ICS in Outlook from a CSV file.
This app works well. We were asked to transpose this application into a Windows service, we made this modification but there, the application just sends emails and no longer invitations as before.
The invite resend code is the same and step by step debugging doesn't show why we are behaving differently.
Do you have any ideas for resolving the situation?

Comment: please add some debugging details to make this not a guesswork

Comment: Sorry but I didn't know what information to add to be clearer. What kind of debugging details might be useful? Thank you for your comment to try to help me anyway.

Comment: Some details about how your app works and about your debugging would be helpful - did you trace it with ProcMon or Wireshark?

Comment: I found a solution by redoing the program from scratch using the .net 6.0 framework with backgroundservice.